# How to create JWT user/access token in nodejs without username/password?

Tags: node.js, jwt, access-token

I am new to nodejs and JWT.
I want to create JWT user/access token in nodejs without user's username/password.
On button click, it should generate an user token and then redirect to next page. Also how to verify user token when page redirect occurs?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a session token to get an access token. The access token is implemented on top of OAuth 2. Nodejs and getting access token are not much related except that you can use nodejs (including any other language) to implement OAuth 2.0.

You can use [this doc](https://developer.okta.com/authentication-guide/implementing-authentication/) to get an access token from Okta.

The flow that does not require "password" is called "implicit flow". Keep in mind you need an active session token.